# MATLAB freqz2 equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, scipy

I'm trying to find a Python library that works equivalently to MATLAB's freqz2 for image processing, since [scipy.signal.freqz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html) only seems to work for 1-D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an amazing library for plotting the 3D surface of the 2-D FFT called [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/). I leave here the lines of code I used to emulate the same behaviour of freqz2 in Python:

```
import scipy.fft as fft
import plotly.graph_objects as go

N = 128
h = fspecial('unsharp', alpha=0.2)
H = fft.fftshift(fft.fft2(h, [N, N]))
f = fft.fftshift(fft.fftfreq(N))
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=f, y=f, z=np.abs(H))])
fig.show()
```

The 3D graphs is interactive, and the fspecial function in python I implemented it myself copying what MATLAB does (I can also post it if asked).
[image]

Which is the equivalent to MATLAB's:

```
h = fspecial('unsharp');
freqz2(h);
```

[image]